# How do I change the motion reference in an animation state during runtime?

Tags: 2d, animation, animation-states, animation-controller

[image]

I tried this solution: https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-change-animation-clips-of-an-animator-state-at-runtime-is-there-a-way/183135/4

But this doesn't work if I try to use a different animation clip. I also want to reuse the same state for swapping different animation clips but this just changes animation clip and not the motion state.

Is there better solution?